# Check what thread is currently doing in python

Tags: python, multithreading

In python, is it possible to ask a thread what its currently doing? Some code might look like this:

```
import threading
import time
import random


def foo():
    a = 'spam'


def bar():
    if random.random() < 0.01:      # go into an infinite loop 1% of the time
        while True:
            x = 42

def run(heartbeat):
    while True:
        foo()
        bar()
        heartbeat.set()

heartbeat = threading.Event()
t = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(heartbeat, ))
t.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if heartbeat.is_set():
        heartbeat.clear()
    else:
        print('Thread appears stuck at the following location: ')
        print(get_thread_position(t))
```

I'm looking to do this to monitor threads to see if they're hanging. The heartbeat event checks whether they're active and progressing normally. However, if they hang somewhere, I'd like to be able to find out where. That's where I've invented `get_thread_position()` which I would like to return something like a traceback to the function its currently executing. That way, I can use that information to figure out how its getting stuck in some infinite loop.

Comment: There's no easy way to check the current state of a thread. You will need to either insert some codes logging the states of a thread occasionally or use a debugger so that you can pause/resume a running thread in the debug mode.

Comment: @hhy - says who? There is a very easy way to do that, check the answer I just posted.

Comment: @zwer, wow, very amazing!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `sys._current_frames()` to pick up a list of top frames for each currently running thread, then find your thread in it and then inspect its frame, something like:

```
import sys

def get_thread_position(thread):
    frame = sys._current_frames().get(thread.ident, None)
    if frame:
        return frame.f_code.co_filename, frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_code.co_firstlineno
```

This will return you a tuple with the filename, function name and line number of the function currently executing in that thread. Of course, you can pick up other frame info as well. If the thread cannot be found (i.e. died in the meantime) it will not return anything (`None`)

Comment: Excellent! From this, I found the documentation that lists all of frame's properties so you can get exactly what you need: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html I found frame.f_lineno to be a useful addition.

Comment: @ericksonla - it all depends what you're looking for, you can even inject bytecode and force the thread to quit. Of course, don't overdo it, this is everything but light on resources... For production code I suggest exploring the stack only when you need to extract debug information (e.g. on errors and such).

Comment: If you want some extra info try adding thread.name in the return statement :D