# Learn the point of execution (module and line number) of one Python thread from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading

We have a complex Python program. I would like to monitor the progress of the program in a secondary thread, which will find out the module and line number in which the main thread is currently executing and report it.

Is there any way for one thread to determine the execution point of another python thread?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add a comment as I'm very new, but please take a look at this [Check what thread is currently doing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290223/check-what-thread-is-currently-doing-in-python)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Do you want to develop this into a code example?